# Mouseover (black + button + zoom in) with css/html

Tags: html, css

I'm totally newbie on html/css but I'll need help.

I want to create a mouseover over a image, the image should be darker, example: a black square with 20% opacity on it and there should be button "more information" + the picture should be zoomed in:

[image]

Already I tried with zoom in, but my footer moving everytime If I go with my mouse over the imge. But my footer should be fixed. Something like this:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/om0bhvwy/

I hope, someone can help me. :)

```
enter code heref
```

Comment: you need to fix the broken link to Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example on w3 schools. you can even play with it in an online editor. It fades it, but doesn't make it darker.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

```
<style>
    img {
        opacity: 0.4;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

    img:hover {
        opacity: 1.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I continued on the code you gave: https://jsfiddle.net/qrso5hbb/
It doesnt show the text on the image yet though. Let me see if I can fix that (my CSS skills aren't that great either). There is probably a better way to do this :P

Comment: thank you, but I mean the reverse of it. image -> mouseover -> image will be darker -> with a button "more information"

Comment: Ok, then you just want to reverse the opacity and alpha(opacity) numbers. make sure if you are using jsfiddle that you hit update and run at the top. The link @StefanJanssen posted will work, just reverse the numbers for hover and normal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend for the image to animate its size change? If not, the simplest way to achieve this is to use the image as a background-image on a containing element, like a `<div>`, which modifies the background size on hover. This `<div>` contains another `<div>`, which acts as a shadow, darkening the parent on hover.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="myPhotoBox">
  <div class="shadowBox">
    <button class="myButton">More Information</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (without vendor prefixes)**

```
.myPhotoBox {
    background-image: url('my-image.jpeg');
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-position:center center;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.myPhotoBox:hover {
    background-size:110% auto;
}
.shadowBox {
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.shadowBox:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.myButton {
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    display:block;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Here's a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gxgcj9pa/1/